# How do I programatically open additional mailboxes in Outlook 2010?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

Our sales department monitor eachothers mailboxes.  Each user has every other users mailboxes open as an additional mailbox.

Whenever a new employee comes along, we have to visit each users' PC to add the additional mailbox(es) to their Outlook profile.  This is a waste of resources and is something I'd like to automate.

There must be a way of programmatically doing this via VBA Script, or some such means?  Searching on Google hasn't been particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model (Outlook VBA) doesn't provide anything for editing user profiles. You can try to use a low level API - Extended MAPI. See [Administering Profiles and Message Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842204.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VBA, you cannot uses Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), you can us its `RDOSession.Stores`.[AddDelegateExchangeMailBoxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostores.htm) method to add a delegate mailbox to the current profile.

If you do not want to log to the profile fist, you can use the `ProfMan` library (I am also its author) to add a mailbox. See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#example6